# Banner image not displaying with responsive image when using Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to use the responsive image feature in Bootstrap. However, when I try to display a banner image using the following code, the banner won't display:

```
<div class="jumbotron">
    <div class="img hero img-responsive"></div>
</div> 

.hero {
  background: url("../images/banner500.jpg") no-repeat;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;      
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

I'm also using AngularJS with SASS.

Any suggestions of how to fix this?

Comment: Are you sure you are linking properly to the image? I have put your code in JSFiddle, changing the background image to an external one and it seems to work: http://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/5356/

Comment: @Pawel Duda I think so. When I inspect with Chrome, the URL link is live and shows the image when I hover over it. Likewise, when I uncheck `height:auto` for the img-responsive class, the banner displays on the page.

Comment: Perhaps some other styles are being applied to the said div, overriding default bootstrap behaviour? EDIT: ensure that your custom stylesheet is being loaded after the bootstrap one.

Comment: @Pawel Duda That's possible, but the only CSS I've added is above.

Comment: In which order .css resources appear in your HTML code?

Comment: @Pawel Duda The css listed above comes last in the head.

Comment: Are you using the SASS version of bootstrap?

Comment: wait, I find the image displayed in jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Alicera/4L0bfun0/ . I think you can try to omit the quotes in URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.img-responsive` has `height: auto` as a CSS property. If you are loading Bootstrap after your own CSS, your `.hero` height is being overridden by Bootstrap. You can solve this by loading Bootstrap first or by changing your CSS selector to `.jumbotron .hero`.

It should be noted here that `.img-responsive` won't do anything for you here anyways. You would use this class directly on an image to make it responsive. What you want is your background image to fit responsively which means that you should set `background-size: cover (or contain)` and adjust the height of the div as needed, likely with `height: 0; padding-bottom: X%` where X% is the percentage height of the image vs its width.

Comment: Thank you. So should I not use `width: 100%`?

Comment: By default, a div is a block level element with a width of 100% so you don't need to declare the width unless you want it to be more or less than 100%. So no - you don't need to use `width: 100%`

Answer (score 0):

Most of your CSS has no effect and some has even errors. Still I'm not sure if we can fix your problem because like the people who commented I guess your problem has something to do with the code we don't see because you should see at least a something...

However some parts you should change definitely and some tips for further trouble shooting/CSSing:

**Proper use of `.img-responsive`**
Like shown in http://getbootstrap.com/css/#images-responsive `.img-responsive` should only be used on `<img>`-tags. What it does (`height: auto;`) cannot work on a `<div>` with a background image.
Now when you use `.img-responsive` you should not set the `height` manually otherwise it will not work because what it does mainly is to set the height to `auto`...

**Proper use of positions and `z-index`**
`left`, `right` and `z-index` should only be used in combination with `position: relative` or `position: absolute`. Therefore in your case they should have no effect but for the sake of readability you should remove them.

**Proper use of `vertical-alignment`**
`vertical-alignment` has only effect on inline elements of which I see none in your case...

**Proper use of `width`**
You are using `width: 100%` on a block element and a block element should always have 100% width of its container. So this attribute again is not necessary in your case (unless there is a lot of code and rules which is influencing the example).
Knowing that also check the effective width of the parent element.

This means from what you posted only two lines of your CSS actually have effect and when you see nothing at all there has to be another problem outside your code, too.